# Laravel - Controller - Mostrar dados de duas tabelas

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, foreach

Estou com dificuldade em mostrar dados relativos a duas tabelas relacionadas.
Controller:
public function index(){

```
    $tabela = capitulo::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate();
    
    $tabela1 = documentacao::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate();

    return view('gestao-documental.index', ['itens' => $tabela, 'itens1' => $tabela1]);

   
}
```

Consigo visualizar o Capitulo mas a documentação não. Poderei estar a fazer mal o return view:

```
<div class="card shadow mb-4">

<div class="card-body">
 <div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
           @foreach($itens as $item)
                <tr>
                    <th> {{$item->capitulo}} </th>
                    
                    

                </tr>
                  
            </thead>
            @foreach($itens1 as $item1)
            <tbody>
            
            <tr>
                <td> {{$item1->documentacao}} </td>
     
                
            </tr>
            @endforeach     

            </tbody>
            @endforeach  
        </table>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente seria interessante saber qual o erro que está ocorrendo, mas já da pra notar que os teus foreach não estão bem estruturados. Por exemplo você começou um foreach abaixo da tag thead e o fechamento do thead está dentro do foreach, ou seja, ele vai iterar quantas vezes existir esse loop, criando varias tag de fechamento de thead onde não existe a de abertura. Outra coisa, eu não sei qual é o teu objetivo, mas a parte da documentação vai ser iterada toda vez que passar o loop do capítulo, por exemplo, quando der o loop do primeiro capítulo, ele vai pegar todas as linhas cadastradas da documentação e iterar, e isso vai tornar a view com código repetido, talvez se sua intenção seja mostrar os dados da tabela documentação que esteja relacionada a um capítulo vinculado, você deve utilizar as funções que você coloca na Modal para buscar este dado. Exemplo:

```
CapituloModel.php

public function documentacoes() {
     return $this->hasMany(DocumentacaoModel::class)
}
```

e na view

```
@foreach($itens->documentacoes as $documentacao)
            <tr>
                <th> {{$documentacao->item_da_documentacao}} </th>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

não sei se ajudei, mas aconselho a estruturar a parte HTML, e explicar qual o erro que está tendo.